# SQL Server CE Where clause issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have a simple SQL Server CE database, trying to update a row in a table.  The following command works:

```
UPDATE ConsoleUsage 
SET TotalCircuits = 123
```

But the above command updates all rows, so what I want is this:

```
UPDATE ConsoleUsage 
SET TotalCircuits = 123 
WHERE Index = 912
```

The intent is to update a single row in the table. But this command fails, giving the following cryptic error message (here using MS suggested format):

> Error Code: 80040E37
>   Message   :  [ UPDATE ConsoleUsage SET TotalCircuits = 123 WHERE Index = 912 ]
>   Minor Err.: 0
>   Source    : SQL Server 2005 Mobile Edition ADO.NET Data Provider
>   Err. Par. : UPDATE ConsoleUsage SET TotalCircuits = 123 WHERE Index = 912

The "Index" column is an index to the table, I've checked all spelling and I've tried this both with and without cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect; and cmd.IndexName = "MainIndex";

What am I missing?

Comment: Update:  tried using a different field in the WHERE clause, this worked.  So there's something wrong with my "Index" column, either its name or its type - it's a "Primary Key" (but should that matter?), type smallint.

Comment: Change the name "Index" to something else ("Id" for example) and try. Is it work?

Comment: I added a new column, named DateCode, same data as Index but not a Primary Key, this now works.  I'll leave Index in place since all tables (I think) must have a primary key.  Not worried about a bit of wasted space, this table does not have many rows.

Answer (score 1):

I think "Index" is a reserved word. Try surrounding it with brackets:

```
UPDATE ConsoleUsage SET TotalCircuits = 123 WHERE [Index] = 912
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the table structure (could you post the create script for the table?) here are a few things I would try:

put square brackets ([]) around all columns and table name to escape them out, just in case
put the schema name of the table to the table, dbo.[ConsoleUsage] instead of [ConsoleUsage]
check to see if [Index] is a char field or not, use '912' instead of 912 if it is

Try converting statement a little:
UPDATE T
SET TotalCircuits = 123
FROM dbo.[ConsoleUsage] T
WHERE T.[Index] = 912

Comment: Tried all of these, same result.

Comment: Could you post the create script for the table?

Comment: Not sure where to find the "create script", I created the table in designer (using studio '05), and I copy the individual get/set methods and Add method from the dataset.Designer.cs file (which is created by studio from a .xsd file which I populate by dragging tables into it from the server explorer) into my code.